# how to connect to our schema by using database

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose, and I find two ways to use schema (in my case, I have "Comment" as schema and "db" to connect to the base:
the first one works correctly:

```
const comment = await new Comment(data);
```

By running the second one:

```
const comment = await new db.Comment(data);
```

I get the following error:

```
(node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.Comment is not a constructor
```

I spent hours to understand why but I don't get the idea, any help, Thanks

Comment: What is db that you want to create instance?

Comment: Is about the connection mongoose, there is my following code:
import config from '../../config.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const connectionOptions = {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
};
mongoose.connect(config.development.dal.url, connectionOptions);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
// test the connection
db.once('open', () => console.log('connected'))
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('Your error  ', error);
  });

export default db;

Comment: can you show me where tell you this to way approach ?

Comment: thanks Mohamed for your interest, I implement the wrong approach, dos'nt work but for now, It works :)